# overriding ng-click from bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

Suppose I am customizing an angularjs bootstrap carousel and making it as a directive. I want to customize the current function that the ng-click calls on each left/right arrow so it calls a custom function before the original function defined in the bootstrap. I know calling multiple functions in ng-click can be done by

```
ng-click = "customFunction();originalFunctionFromBootstrap()"
```

But, in angular carousel, the left and right arrow is defined inside its bootstrap template and I don't want to modify the template using $templatecache.
Is there a way to add new ng-click in my controller without having to modify the template cache?

EDIT:
The current workaround that I can have is using

```
document.querySelector('.left.carousel-control').addEventListener('click', function(){...})
```

And of course this is not angular way of doing this. Plus, if I use ng-click from ng-touch, this will not be called as well. Is there a way on how to modify the ng-click?

Comment: Have you considered using the `slide.bs.carousel` event callback? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: @isherwood so your suggestion is to call custom function $on(slide.bs.carousel)?

Comment: Right. You should be able to add any custom behavior before or after the slide event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is:

```
document.querySelector('.left.carousel-control').setAttribute('ng-click', 'customFunction()');
$compile(document.querySelector('.left.carousel-control'))(scope);
```

And this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit the scope of the directive you can save the library function in a variable and override the function with your logic. Then call the function that you saved on a variable so everything keep working.

```
var _superClickMethod = scope.originalFunctionFromBootstrap;
scope.originalFunctionFromBootstrap = function () {
  // custom logic
  _superClickMethod();
}
```

Other solution is to wrap the carrusel bootstrap plugin in a directive of yours. I recommend the last option.

Comment: I have the carousel wrapped inside a directive of mine. I created a new directive that basically is a customized carousel. But how do I customize the ngclick? sorry I still don't get it

Comment: I mean the bootstrap carrousel. Not the angular-bootstrap carrousel

Comment: ah I see ya currently I have the angular-bootstrap carousel instead. and I don't inherit the scope of the directive so when I try to save the library function scope.originalFunctionFromBootstrap it's undefined

Comment: can you add your directive and the angular-bootstrap directive in the same element. I think that could do the trick for the inheritance. but you have to add terminal attribute to your directive so it loads the last.<element bootstrap-directive your-custom-directive>